# JHipster Authenticating a user connecting to REST end points

Tags: spring-security, oauth, jhipster

I am very new to JHipster... but, I am trying to learn.

What i am trying to figure out is, what needs to be implemented for OAuth with social login (G+) to work?

suppose i am making a REST service that supplies weather data via jhipster. connecting to the service is an android app. the app has its own OAuth flow, but I want to lock down the REST service.

Do i need to implement a separate OAuth flow for the Rest service? does that mean the user would have top log in twice? I don't see much in the way of documentation on what gets created with jhipster, and what needs to be generated ontop of it to implement social login.

Comment: so, you are looking for a social login or a oauth2 server tutorial? In other words: do you want your JHipster be an identity provider or do you want a user to authenticate to your JHipster by an foreign identity provider, such as G+ ?

Comment: I want to use  a foreign identity provider. specifically, G+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the closest I could come up with was the following:
https://jhipster.github.io/tips/012_tip_add_new_spring_social_connector.html
http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/#_social_login_manual

Answer (score 0):

JHipster supports social login out of the box for Google. For this, it is sufficient to use the usual **session authentication** and the "Social Login" in **additional options**. In detail, you select this option in the generator, and will have to fill additional details for your social accounts,

you will have a auto generated configuration in `application.yaml` with this content

```
social:
    # see https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow#step_1_create_a_client_id_and_client_secret
    google:
        client-id: xxx
        client-secret: xxx

    # see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/v2.2
    facebook:
        client-id: xxx
        client-secret: xxx

    # see https://apps.twitter.com/app/
    twitter:
        client-id: xxx
        client-secret: xxx
```

where you just add your data.

If you are only interested in google, you can disable unneeded components as you need it, manually in your generated application.

Comment: Steinmam - I did that with no results. when I hit an endpoint, It just returns status 4xx